# Use of login/logout is inconsistent and incorrect

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, login, logout, grammar

The terms *login* and *logout* are used inconsistently and incorrectly. The links up there in the header and the associated buttons should use the [verb form](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/log_in) *log in* and *log out* because they're actions.

Update: though fixed once, the new March 2011 popup [has it wrong again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EAXR.png).

Comment: *Sits down with popcorn and watches chaos ensue.*

Comment: It's all about the whitespace between the words!

Comment: As someone who owns physical dictionaries and related grammar texts in the *dozens*, I have to agree completely with John.

Comment: I wonder if this will invoke the same S that Atwood was going to use with regard to the singular and plural debate? Or will this be a space he will use to beat the OP to death? :)

Comment: @Ólafur - Oi. Share!

Comment: @Diago *hands over* you want some salt with that? Soda's in the fridge. (oh wait, I'm in Iceland, everything is a fridge)

Comment: +1 for promoting the English language.

Comment: +1, but I prefer *Sign In* and *Sign Out* myself. Log In and Log Out is soooo old skool.

Comment: I must admit that I switched to Sign In and Sign Out for my own Web applications a while ago. Log In/Log Out still feels a bit techie for a general audience to me.

Comment: Unless I just loginned, I agree it's "log in".

Comment: +1 for taking the language back.

Comment: Come on Jeff, so correct use of language is a _feature_ now?! ;-)

Comment: Can't upvote this enough. It is highly irritating to see language destroyed (and we wonder why kids bastardize the language..).

Comment: Careers still use the one-word form.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a number of non-english speakers *logging in* to StackOverflow (including me).  There also is some rant about badly formulated questions, when the guys barely know the language adopted here.

If one of the aims is to satisfy the former and to decrease the latter, then the captions should be as polished as possible.  I cannot judge whether "log in" form is better than "login", it's English-speaking admins who should.  But it's easy to imagine that the caption was incorrect for too long because those who know the language, know where the mistake is, and those who don't, think that it's the correct way to spell it.

Fix it, please, if it's incorrect.  I'm not really sure, but...

Answer (score 7):

I find it quite ironic that we have a badge named after [the highly-regarded and often-named "Bible of English Grammar"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/020530902X) yet we cannot follow its own principles.

Here's what 20 seconds of googling turned up:

- [University of Rochester Grammar Style Guide](http://www.rochester.edu/news/styleguide/grammar.html)
- [oh hey look, a stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307528/login-or-log-in)
- [The truth about grammar: bailout versus bail out](http://www.thetruthaboutgrammar.com/2009/06/03/bailout-versus-bail-out/)
- and there are so many more...

Answer (score -6):

While I'm not against this change, I can't muster any enthusiasm for it either. If we've gone more than a year without this being a problem in the slightest, I don't see how the next year would be any different.

Comment: No problem on the enthusiasm front, just get Geoff or Jarrod to do it, should only take about ten minutes!

I know you love your iPhone Jeff (I <3 mine too!) and one of the things that makes it great is phenomenal attention to detail. Wouldn't this change fit in with the spirit of improving Stack Overflow just a little bit every day?

Comment: FWIW, I would have raised it earlier if I thought it would have made a difference.

Comment: I bet it took Jeff more time to answer this question than it would take to fix it. :)

Comment: Since you fixed the spelling before, maybe we can ask again: the new March 2011 popup [has it wrong again](http://i.imgur.com/1EAXR.png).