# Fix "login" to verb "log in" on question pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, wording, grammar

On the bottom of question pages is a prompt to "Sign up or [login](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl=/questions/5302/log-in-to-or-log-into-or-login-to#new-answer)":

[image: Screenshot showing: Sign up or login]

But *login* is a noun and *log in* is the verb.

See http://loginisnotaverb.com/ and ["log in to" or "log into" or "login to"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5302/log-in-to-or-log-into-or-login-to).

The prompt should use verbs: "Sign up or log in".

(If you click the "log in" link, the next page uses "log in" and "login" correctly.)

Comment: Maybe in British English or American English... In Internet English login appears to be a verb, too. After all language is not what's in the books, but how people use it.

Comment: @Molot In Internet English, *u* is a word. SE has fixed this before, [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109539/change-login-to-log-in-and-logout-to-log-out) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29229/use-of-login-logout-is-inconsistent-and-incorrect)

Comment: @Mołot simple test: do you say "he logins, I loginned, we are loginning", or do you say "he logs in, I logged in, we are logging in"? QED.

Comment: @ЯegDwight: standard English is full of defective verbs; why can't Internet English have some of its own?

Comment: @Wooble oh I'm fine with defective verbs. I'm not fine with inconsistency, though. Make it "Signup and login", and make it that *on every SE page everywhere ever*, and you can countin me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will be corrected as soon as build revs 2014.1.24.*