# "log in" should be "login"

Tags: discussion, grammar

From https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl=https%3a%2f%2farea51.stackexchange.com%2fusers%2flogin-or-signup%2fdelegated%3freturnurl%3dhttps%253a%252f%252farea51.stackexchange.com%26type%3dlogin&cdl=1

> Completing log in to Area 51
>
> You will be redirected automatically

"log in" should be "login".

Comment: I feel like log in is correct too in this context

Comment: @JourneymanGeek let's ask https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/327693/3023

Comment: Not a native speaker but I believe it should be either "login to" or "logging into". BTW, the difference between "login" and "log in" was asked and answered here: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/5302/288445

Comment: @Exampleperson no. It's already "Log in" (without the quotes) everywhere. I honestly have no idea why one would want to make something inconsistent, and likely not correct grammar wise as well. It is two words: first word is "log", second word "in". They come together to form something which most people are familiar with.

Comment: Related: *[Fix "login" to verb "log in" on question pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217201/)* (2014) and [Use of login/logout is inconsistent and incorrect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29229/* (2009)

Comment: I agree that *log in(to)* is the spelling for the verb, and *log-in* or *login* for the noun. In this case, it is the noun: what are you completing? I'm completing the log-in. There is no log that I'm completing: that word has a different meaning. The confusion is because of the slightly awkward placement of *to* after the noun: you'd normally see either just *completing log-in*, or *logging into x*, not *completing log-in to x*, but that is what it must be here (hyphen optional but i.m.o. better).

Answer (score -1):

> "log in" should be "login"

Incorrect.

Neither is [wrong](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/144883/66746), when [used and spelled correctly](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/20434/66746).

> **login** (noun) - A combination of a user's identification and password used to enter a computer, program, network, etc.
> **log in** (verb) - Enter a computer.

Source: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/login#Noun

> Noun
> **login** (plural logins)
>
> 1. (computing) A combination of a user's identification and password used to enter a computer, program, network, etc.
>
>    - I've forgotten my **login** again.
> 2. (computing) The process of logging in.
>
>    - Your **login** failed because you weren't connected to the office network.

Source: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/login#Verb

> Verb
> **login**
>
> 1. **M̳i̳s̳s̳p̳e̳l̳l̳i̳n̳g̳** of **log in**.

Source: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/log_in#Verb

> Verb
> **log in** (third-person singular simple present **logs in**, present participle **logging in**, simple past and past participle **logged in**)
>
> 1. (computing) To gain access to a computer system, usually by providing a previously agreed upon username and password.
>
>    - I would like to **log in** to check my e-mail, but I can't remember my password.

Further reading: http://www.notaverb.com/login

> Despite what many people --mostly in the computer field-- think, "login" is not a verb. It's simply not.

It's the same, but an antonym, for
[**logout**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/logout#Noun) and [**log out**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/log_out#Verb).

Comment: But isn't it used as a noun here (i.e., the process of logging in)?

Comment: You're not logging in, it's the log in that's being completed; it's post-login, after entering your information and submitting it.